# How to fix array.forEach not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fetch list of jobs from freelancer api and show the list of jobs and be able to save the jobs. In this process I am maintaining `savedGigs` array, where I am pushing saved Item to an array. 
I am getting an error:

> `savedGigs.forEach` is not a function.

Need help with this.

```js
checkIfGigIsSaved = (savedGigs, freelancerGigId) => {
  let isLiked = false;
  savedGigs.forEach(gigItem => {
    if (gigItem.gigId === freelancerGigId && !isLiked) {
      isLiked = true;
    }
  });
  return isLiked;
}

componentDidMount() {
  let interval = window.setInterval(() => {
    if (uid !== null) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      const promise1 = this.fetchSavedGigs();
      const promise2 = this.fetchFreelancerJobs();
      let currentState = this.state;

      Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(values => {
        const savedGigs = values[0];
        const freelancerJobs = values[1].data.result.projects;
        freelancerJobs.forEach(project => {
          currentState.listOfJobs.push({
            bid_avg: project.bid_stats.bid_avg,
            bid_count: project.bid_stats.bid_count,
            budget_minimum: project.budget.minimum,
            budget_maximum: project.budget.maximum,
            frontend_project_status: project.frontend_project_status,
            time_submitted: project.time_submitted,
            title: project.title,
            type: project.type,
            preview_description: project.preview_description,
            id: project.id,
            isLiked: this.checkIfGigIsSaved(savedGigs, project.id)
          });
        });

        this.setState({
          listOfJobs: currentState.listOfJobs,
          isFreelancerApiSuccess: true,
          freelancerApiInProgress: false,
          savedGigs: savedGigs
        });
      });
    }
  }, 250);
}
```

`values[0]` is array of objects as

```
[ { gigId: 18489216, rank: 1 }, { gigId: 18489200, rank: 2 }, { gigId: 18489102, rank: 3 } ]
```

and `value[1]` is response from the free lancer api if that helps. I am unable to post the entire response

Comment: what is the value of `values` from promise?

Comment: You should show your whole code here.

Comment: and what is `freelancerJobs`?

Comment: What is `savedGigs` in `checkIfGigIsSaved` (at the moment when you get error)? Does it look like the `savedGigs` you posted? Does it happen on first project, or some next?

Comment: if it ends up that freelancerJobs is not an array, but an object, then you should use Object.keys(freelancerJobs).forEach => ...

Answer (score 1):

I see this debugging technique a lot, where people get an error like the one you have now, and assume javascript is wrong somewhere. You have not misspelled `.forEach` or misspelled the variable name. Then what is left, is that `savedGigs` is not an array.

I know, I know, you think it is.
But it isn't, that is what the error `savedGigs.forEach is not a function.` is very clear about.
It might be something very similar to an array, like an object with one property that contains the array (eg. `{ data: [...] }`).

To make sure, log the data right before the place where the error occurs. You will see that it is indeed not an array.

```
checkIfGigIsSaved = (savedGigs, freelancerGigId) => {
  let isLiked = false;
  // Log **right here**, which is important to get the exact value before the error
  console.log('savedGigs:', savedGigs);
  savedGigs.forEach(gigItem => {
```

I hope you will figure it out with these steps, because you seem to have extracted the data from a different variable. I wanted to make clear that if you get this error, the cause is that the variable is **actually not an array**. However much you expect it to be an array, if you get this error, it is not.

Comment: Thank you every one for the reply. As Michiel Dral mentioned even though I expected it to be an array but it is not an array so I fixed this by

Comment: using Object.keys(savedGigs).forEach(gigItem